# Increasing equivalency of $f'(x)e^{ax}$ and $f'(x)+af(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to show that $f'(x)e^{ax}$ is increasing is equivalent to saying that $f'(x)+a f(x)$ is increasing, if we only assume $f$ is continously differential on $(0,\infty)$.

If $f$ is twice differential, then it is OK by differential method, since their derivatives have the same sign.

Comment: Do you mean "equivalent to saying that $f' \color{red}'(x) + af(x)$ is increasing"?

Comment: @Mattos No. Just $f'(x)+af(x)$ is increasing. You can calculate their derivatives have the same sign if $f\in C^2$...